# Script tag is not working in SartajPHP Temp File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert JavaScript code into jQuery ready function. But this code is not working ..

```
<script runas="jsfunctioncode" renderonce="true">
    $("#srchbtn").on("click",function(){
        $("#form2").attr("action","<?= getEventPath("usersrch"); ?>"); 
        form2_submit('');
    });
</script>
```

Error Message:- Incomplete attributes in script tag.

Answer (score 2):

You forget attribute function in script tag ..
use

```
<script runas="jsfunctioncode" function="ready" renderonce="true">
    $("#srchbtn").on("click",function(){
        $("#form2").attr("action","<?php echo getEventPath("usersrch"); ?>"); 
        form2_submit('');
    });
</script>
```